# Model instance method saving image under wrong directory when editing existing object?

Tags: django, python-3.x, image-processing, django-models, python-imaging-library

This is a tricky one for me unfortunately. I have a GalleryImage model that has a instance method, cropper, that takes the image uploaded to image field and crops it. Then basically does some things that I don't quite understand to crop the image and save it to crop_image field.
Creating new objects everything works as expected but when I edit an existing object it saves the cropped image in the wrong directory. (very wrong).

Edit: I thought I might mention that I am using Pillow Image module.

The directory ends up like this when editing existing object:
https://gyazo.com/e9b2abcbfc997f911a1bf1e77d4566b6

Here is my code:

```
class GalleryImage(models.Model):
    """Represents a "gallery image object" inside system."""

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery/img/%Y/%m/%d',
                              validators=[validators.val_img_exten])
    crop_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='gallery/crops/%Y/%m/%d',
                                   validators=[validators.val_img_exten],
                                   blank=True, null=True)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['image','title']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        crop_f, cr_io, n_name = self.cropper()
        self.crop_image.save(name=n_name,
                            content=ContentFile(cr_io.getvalue()), save=False)
        return super(GalleryImage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def cropper(self):
        if self.image:
            new_file = ContentFile(self.image.read())
            new_name = (self.image.name.split('.')[0] +
                       '_copy.' + self.image.name.split('.')[1])
            new_file.name = new_name
            self.crop_image = new_file

            if self.crop_image:
                image = Image.open(self.crop_image)
                exten = self.crop_image.name.split('.')[1].lower()
                if exten == 'jpg':
                    exten = 'jpeg'
                longer_side = max(image.size)
                hp = (longer_side - image.size[0]) / 2
                vp = (longer_side - image.size[1]) / 2

                c_img = Image.open(self.crop_image)
                crop = c_img.crop(
                    (
                        -hp,
                        -vp,
                        c_img.size[0] + hp,
                        c_img.size[1] + vp
                    )
                )
                crop_io = BytesIO()
                crop.save(crop_io, format=exten)
                return crop, crop_io, new_name
```

I really need this figured out so if anyone can point me in the right direction, whether it is documentation, example or advice to start over. Thank you.

Comment: It feels weird that cropper has no effect when `self.image` is `None`. Ideally you'd always ensure that it does have self.image, so it behaves the same whether it's an update or not. Anyway, this might be a good question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) once you get it working.

Comment: Hmm.. Good point. I still haven't figured it out yet. @AndreTerra

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing something like this. Here you can use "instance" object

```
def get_upload_file_name(instance ,filename):
    return "uploaded_images/%s_%s" %(datetime.datetime.now(),filename)


class ModelClass(models.Model):
     photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name,null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is that the error comes from how you're splitting path and filename using `split()` rather than using `os.path`.

Within `cropper()`, use e.g.

```
filepath, filename = os.path.split(self.image.name)
filename, exten = os.path.splitext(filename)
```

Then set `new_name = filepath + filename + '_copy.' + exten`

Comment: Although this is a cleaner way of getting the filename, this doesn't fix the saving issue.. I really appreciate the help regardless. @AndreTerra